# Angular 2 - using a PDF Viewer to display PDF obtained from a web service API

Tags: angular, pdf

I am new to Angular 2 and it has been a while since I've done web development so I'm rusty.  I was able to get my small angular 2 app up and running fairly quickly.  However, I'm stuck on what pdf viewer to use to display a PDF that was retrieved via a web API in my web browser (SPA) (not in a new browser window).  I was successful in converting my response from the web api into a blob and displaying it in a new browser/tab window by doing the following:

my.ts file:

```
 onGetFullPdf() {
    this.pasSignerService.getPasFormFullPdf()
      .subscribe(
        (pdfBlob: Blob) => {
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
          // this works but opens it in a new window
          window.open(fileURL);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get a PDF (from a web api) displayed on my browser tab (not a new tab)?  I'd like to have all of the nice PDF controls.  I found pdf.js_viewer but that is for angularJS (not angular 2/4/x).  I saw one called ng2-pdf-viewer but it doesn't seem to be full featured.  I feel like I'm missing something basic.

- Do I need to install a pdf viewer or is there some other way to accomplish my goals?
- Don't browsers come with PDF viewer built in?
- Can I take advantage of them?
- Why would I need to download one?

Comment: I'm using ng2-pdf-viewer,  and you are correct that the basic component just displays the PDF, with no controls. But the project has a sample of a full-featured viewer with all of the controls.

Answer (score 1):

you can set content type on the response header to "application/pdf"
most of the new browsers have nice controller set and full functionality to support and use as a pdf reader.
You just need to tell the browser: 'hey im sending you a pdf!", browser will take care of the rest.

on asp.net=>

```
context.response.ContentType="application/pdf";
```

on js=>

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

chrome & edge controllers for pdf files
[image]

[image]